# HTML e CSS - Centralizar Tabs ao centro da página

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

É uma pergunta newbie, mas estou com esta dificuldade.

Tenho 3 tabs que estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria que ficassem no centro desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também ao invés de texto, gostaria de colocar imagens.

Meu CSS para as tabs estão desta forma:

```
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -4px;    
    background-color: #36D100;
    position:sticky;
    height: 102px;
    width: 100%;

}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: center;

    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 95px;
    width: 186px;

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-top: none;
}
```

E meu HTML, desta forma:

```
 <content>




        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" active>London</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
        </div>

        <div id="London" class="tabcontent" data-ng-click="London">
            <h3>London</h3>
            <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            function openCity(evt, cityName) {
                var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
                tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
                for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
                evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

        </script>

    </content>
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione apenas duas linhas na classe `.tab` para centralizar:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Você pode usar imagens como `background` criando uma `class` personalizada para cada botão:

```
   .tokyo{
       background-image: url(http://canada-tokyo.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/TokyoTokyo.png);
       background-size:cover;
   }

   .paris{
       background-image: url(http://www.parkspics.com/France/Paris.gif);
       background-size:cover;
   }

   .london{
       background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-london-icon-set-file-eps-format-35922984.jpg);
       background-size:cover;
   }
```

```css
.tokyo{
    background-image: url(http://canada-tokyo.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/TokyoTokyo.png);
    background-size:cover;
}

.paris{
    background-image: url(http://www.parkspics.com/France/Paris.gif);
    background-size:cover;
}

.london{
    background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-london-icon-set-file-eps-format-35922984.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}

div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -4px;    
    background-color: #36D100;
    position:sticky;
    height: 102px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: center;

    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 95px;
    width: 186px;

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks london" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" active></button>
      <button class="tablinks paris" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')"></button>
      <button class="tablinks tokyo" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')"></button>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="tabcontent" data-ng-click="London">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!

Comment: @Ramos Atualizei a resposta dando dica de como colocar imagem em vez de texto.

Comment: Sabe como posso colocar as imagens, no lugar dos textos?

Comment: @Ramos o `background-size:cover;` é opcional. Serve apenas no meu exemplo pra imagem caber no botão.